# PHP file_put_contents not saving but no error/warning shown

Tags: php

I'm trying to load a file, add some text and then save the file, I have this:

```
$css = file_get_contents("unzipped/$folder/style.css");
if(file_put_contents("ADD THIS " . $css, "unzipped/$folder/style.css")){
   echo("All Done!"); 
}
```

and even though 'All Done!' is echoed the contents of the file isn't changing.

Any ideas? :S

**EDIT:**

I also want to add that if I echo `$css` the contents of the file is shown correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The path to the file is the first argument to `file_put_contents`.

```
$css = file_get_contents("unzipped/$folder/style.css");
if(file_put_contents("unzipped/$folder/style.css", "ADD THIS " . $css)){
   echo("All Done!"); 
}
```

Comment: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

Answer (score 12):

Your parameters are in the wrong order. See the [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) documentation. Your corrected code:

```
$css = file_get_contents("unzipped/$folder/style.css");
if(file_put_contents("unzipped/$folder/style.css", "ADD THIS " . $css)){
   echo("All Done!"); 
}
```

You'll probably notice a file called "ADD THIS " with the contents of that file, as the file name. The contents of the crazily named file will be whatever `unzipped/$folder/style.css` would parse out to.

Answer (score 0):

When you use functions that might return a zero as a valid result you should use strict type comparison (===)

```
if(file_put_contents("ADD THIS " . $css, "unzipped/$folder/style.css") === true){
   echo("All Done!"); 
}
```

Comment: Holodoc, that doesn't fix his problem though.

Comment: I commented because there are still a lot people out there ignoring  warnings on php.net about the necessity to always use strict comparison with functions which might return zero as a valid result.

There are absolutely valid situations in which `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` might return zero i.e. when there was nothing read from a file or written to it. In case the usual type juggling is used the returned zero would indicate a failed reading / writing operation which is wrong. That's the exact reason why strict comparison has to be used in these situations.

Comment: @holodoc Agreed except you want !== false as the function returns false on failure and the number of bytes written on success.